# error: The requested URL returned error: 403 while accessing https://github.com/cetic/foren.git/info/refs

Tags: git

im getting Error 403:fatal:HTTP request failed while trying to clone to git.
im trying to use foren6 diagnosis tool.i've found some answers from the internet like upgrading git. i've done it and dint workout either. how can i solve this error.Is there anyother way to get access to the source code?

Comment: Is https://github.com/cetic/foren.git/info/refs the url you are using for cloning?

Comment: no. im using https://github.com/cetic/foren6.git

Comment: What client are you using to clone the repository?

Comment: how can i connect mote to USB in simulation?